# How to provide default values for variables set with list()?

Tags: php, arrays, list

Assume I have a array like this:

```
$arr1 = ('red', 'blue');
```

and then I do:

```
list($color1, $color2, $color3) = $arr1;
```

I get 2 nice variables with the array values.

Is it possible to somehow set `$color3` to have a default value in case it's not present in the array, but with as little code as possible (without using `if` checks and stuff like that)?

I tried with `list($color1 = 'default', $color2 = 'default', $color3 = 'default') = $arr1;` but it doesn't work...

Comment: You can pre-assign `$colorN` and let `list` overwrite the default values. However, if `$arr1` does not have enough items you will be getting notices if you do that. IMHO, code that gives notices should be rewritten to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$yourColors = array('red', 'green');
$defaultColors = array('yellow', 'blue', 'cyan');

list($color1, $color2, $color3) = $yourColors + $defaultColors;
```

`$color1` will be '*red*'

`$color2` will be '*green*'

`$color3` will be '*cyan*'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$color1 = $color2 = $color3 = array();  // ...or whatever else you want it to be set to
list($color1, $color2, $color3) = $arr1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you initialize your variables first with a default value, than it will be possible,

```
$color1 = $color2 = $color3 =" Blue";

$arr1 = array('red','green');
list($color1, $color2, $color3) = $arr1;
```

now $color3 will not be set in the list function; so it will keep its original value;